# Greek Blue Paper

Tags: air-travel, schengen, uk, customs-and-immigration, greece

I am going to travel to UK, I have a Greek blue paper that is my residence,
I am a student in Greece. I am South American Citizen with a valid visa for UK.

If I travel to UK would I be able to reenter Greece again with my blue paper, or would have problems with Airlines letting me go? My Schengen visa has expired.

Comment: Getting out to anywhere other than your home country will be a problem.  They don't like it because it gives illegals the opportunity to move elsewhere and elude the authorities.  Can you not get a new Schengen?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘blue paper‘? Does it have a name? What's your exact status?

Comment: @Relaxed, temporary immigration document.  Should NOT be confused with the BLUE CARD programme run by BUNAC.

Answer (score 4):

If you only hold a valid bebaiosi, [you can only leave Greece to travel and return to your home country](http://www.yptp.gr/index.php?option=ozo_content&lang=GR&perform=view&id=5331&Itemid=604). If you travel elsewhere, [you may be denied entry](http://livingingreece.gr/2007/10/16/im-a-non-eu-citizen-in-greece-am-i-allowed-to-travel-when-i-wish/) on return to Greece. You should wait until you receive your residence permit (Άδεια Παραμονής) before traveling to other countries.

Comment: Are you Sure? Because in IATA website they said that It woulkd be fine. My worry is when I take the aircraft from London to Athens, they may not allow me to enter as I have just my bebaiosi. So confused people said it ok other people its not. Actually Immigration I ask and said its fine as well... But uou have a lot of sense...