# entering Greece with blue paper

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, greece, residency

I applied for a Greek residence permit two months ago and got my blue paper. In the meantime, I returned to my home country and my Schengen has expired.

Now, I will go to Athens to collect my residence permit and I will travel for the first time with my blue paper. I just want to make sure that there will be no problems while entering Greece. Can anyone who has entered Greece with a blue paper share their experience?

Comment: Uh, do you mean a "Blue Card" (a work authorization/visa)?

Comment: @mkennedy Please upload a copy of the "blue paper", blacking out personal details. If I see exactly what it is, I can give you a confident answer

Comment: @Crazydre see [this clarification](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45363/greek-blue-paper) on a similar question

Comment: @Dorothy I think the other question answers this one. Should we vote to mark this one as a duplicate?

Comment: @mkennedy I agree; I'll do it now.